# Autolayout - Dynamic View height in different device and orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, autolayout, xcode6

Finally somehow i managed to create the login view using auto layout (Still not sure, if its correct or not). everything looks good in different devices as well as in both the orientations also.

What i want to achieve now is  when user clicks on any textfield my gray view scrolls up and when tapping on the return key on the keyboard it should go down to its initial position.

After doing a lot of googling, I came to know is I have to give top spacing margin related to the parent view (self.view) and set change the constraints programmatically like below:

self.topSpaceConstraint.constant = 50 (Set Priority to 999 in my code)
 self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

But when i am doing so, my container view (Gray view) squeezes. I am not able to figure it out why, I want a fixed height constraint (Set Priority to 1000 in my code) along with vertical and horizontal center. Please suggest how to scroll the container view with proper auto layout constraints.[image: storyboard screenshot]

Comment: Why are you using a vertical center constraint if you want to move the gray view? You should remove it. You need space constraint on top and bottom of the gray view. Set one you prefer as inequality (<= for top >= for bottom) and change the constant value of the fixed one. So if the bottom space is fixed add the keyboard height to constant else subtract from top space constant.

Comment: @GonjiDev If i remove the vertical center constraint with your suggestions, then my gray view squeezes. I want it for constant width and height. So that it looks good in all device and also center aligned.

Comment: You cannot have fixed width unless the width is less than the minimum screen width. Did you add the other constraints? You also need the fixed height constraint. If you want to use the center vertical then you have to remove it at runtime to move the view because you will have conflicting constraints. If you upload your project somewhere maybe I can help you.

Comment: @GonjiDev Thanks for your kindness, From here you can have my sample app. http://www.wikiupload.com/WR4W163TG0YS589 Please check the login form, Also please let me know your changes, So that I can rectify my mistakes in future. Thanks.

Comment: [Here](http://www.filedropper.com/formsautolayout2) you can find my solution. I don't have much time to explain everything so look at the storyboard and the viewController, you'll understand!

Comment: Thanks @GonjiDev, It is what i am looking for. Thanks for your efforts and making me clear about the runtime approach.